# How to access list of objects inside a list of Objects in Dart

Tags: json, list, flutter, object

Creating tabs with types and need to display in Corresponding TabView..

```
 var listOfItem = [
    {
      "types": "ARABIAN",
      "restaurants": [
        {
          "name": "ZauZau Restaurants",
          "location": "Mascat, Oman",
          "kms": "1.0 kms"
        },
        {
          "name": "MauMau Restaurants",
          "location": "Calicut, Oman",
          "kms": "2.0 kms"
        },
        {
          "name": "ChaCha Restaurants",
          "location": "Charat, Oman",
          "kms": "2.5 kms"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "types": "COFFEE SHOP",
      "restaurants": [
        {
          "name": "ZauZau Restaurants",
          "location": "Mascat, Oman",
          "kms": "1.0 kms"
        },
      ]
    },
  ];
```

This is my list of objects
I am accessing its "restaurants" by

```
listOfItem.asMap().entries.map((e) => print(e.value['restaurants'])).toList();
```

And I need to map that particular List
Trying long time. I didn't get any idea on this
BTW I am new to coding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick answer

You can nest two mapping of your JSON data:

```
listOfItem.map((category) => Column(
  children: (category['restaurants'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
      .map((restaurant) => Text(restaurant['name'])).toList()
).toList();
```

Remember to use `toList()` as a `map` operation does not return a `List` but an `Iterable`.

### Basic Full Solution

Here is a first solution based on your data and the [Flutter Tabs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs).

[image]

#### Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: data.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Restaurants'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: data.map((category) => Tab(text: category['types'])).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: data
              .map((category) => ListView(
                    children:
                        (category['restaurants'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
                            .map(
                              (restaurant) => ListTile(
                                title: Text(restaurant['name']),
                                subtitle: Text(restaurant['location']),
                              ),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final data = [
  {
    "types": "ARABIAN",
    "restaurants": [
      {
        "name": "ZauZau Restaurants",
        "location": "Mascat, Oman",
        "kms": "1.0 kms"
      },
      {
        "name": "MauMau Restaurants",
        "location": "Calicut, Oman",
        "kms": "2.0 kms"
      },
      {
        "name": "ChaCha Restaurants",
        "location": "Charat, Oman",
        "kms": "2.5 kms"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "types": "COFFEE SHOP",
    "restaurants": [
      {
        "name": "ZauZau Restaurants",
        "location": "Mascat, Oman",
        "kms": "1.0 kms"
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

---

### Advanced Full Solution

And here is a second solution providing exactly the same visual but managing specific Domain Entities `Restaurant` & `RestaurantCategory`.

It introduces concepts such as State Management and JSON Serialization.

#### Full source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

part '66318447.tabs.freezed.dart';
part '66318447.tabs.g.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = useProvider(dataProvider).state;
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: data.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Restaurants'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: data.map((category) => Tab(text: category.name)).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: data
              .map((category) => ListView(
                    children: category.restaurants
                        .map(
                          (restaurant) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(restaurant.name),
                            subtitle: Text(
                                '${restaurant.location} (${restaurant.kms} away)'),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final dataProvider = StateProvider<List<RestaurantCategory>>(
    (ref) => data.map((json) => RestaurantCategory.fromJson(json)).toList());

@freezed
abstract class Restaurant with _$Restaurant {
  const factory Restaurant(String name, String location, String kms) =
      _Restaurant;

  factory Restaurant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$RestaurantFromJson(json);
}

@freezed
abstract class RestaurantCategory with _$RestaurantCategory {
  const factory RestaurantCategory(String name, List<Restaurant> restaurants) =
      _RestaurantCategory;

  factory RestaurantCategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$RestaurantCategoryFromJson(json);
}

final data = [
  {
    "name": "ARABIAN",
    "restaurants": [
      {
        "name": "ZauZau Restaurants",
        "location": "Mascat, Oman",
        "kms": "1.0 kms"
      },
      {
        "name": "MauMau Restaurants",
        "location": "Calicut, Oman",
        "kms": "2.0 kms"
      },
      {
        "name": "ChaCha Restaurants",
        "location": "Charat, Oman",
        "kms": "2.5 kms"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "COFFEE SHOP",
    "restaurants": [
      {
        "name": "ZauZau Restaurants",
        "location": "Mascat, Oman",
        "kms": "1.0 kms"
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this loop:

```
for (final x in listOfItem){
    //x is the current object here
    for (final y in x["restaurants"]){
        //y is the current restaurant
        print(y["property you want"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So then, you can use that similar loop to loop in the restaurants and retrieve the properties:

for (final x in listOfItem){
    for (final y in x["restaurants"]){
        print(y);
    }
}

Comment: I see that my code in comment is not readable very well. So I will edit answer.

Comment: Thank you, yes the solution is nested loops. If you solve the problem, can you please mark my answer as solution?